# Calculate Cartasian product Itertools.product without comma(Delimiter)

Tags: python, python-3.x, delimiter, python-itertools, cartesian-product

Hello i just keep wondering how do we calculate cartesian product(intertools.product(*somelist)) BUT without printing the Comma ?

I WANT IT TO PRINT SOMETHING LIKE THIS!

```
So, if the first input is of the form:  A, B, .. X
        and the second is of the form:  1, 2, .. n
the output would be of the form:  
  ["A 1", "A 2", .. "An", "B 1", "B 2", .. "Bn", .. "X 1", "X 2", .. "Xn"]

(where the ".." indicates there can be more elements in between).  

Here is a more specific case:
    For inputs:  blue, electric, floating 
           and:  cheese, eel
we would get:
  ["blue cheese", "electric cheese", "floating cheese", "blue eel",...........

HOWEVER WHEN I DO 
listA=[] #Creating a list
listB=[]#Creating a second list
listC=[]
input_listA=input( "Enter second comma separated list of int: " )
listA.append(input_listA)
input_listB = input( "Enter first comma separated list of strings: " )
listB.append(input_listB)
listC.append(listB)
listC.append(listA)

for i in itertools.product(*listA,*listB):
      print(i)
```

it give this output:

> INPUT: Enter second comma separated list of int: A, B, C 
>   Enter first comma separated list of strings: 1, 2, 3 ('A', '1') ('A', ',') ('A', '
>   ') ('A', '2') ('A', ',') ('A', ' ') ('A', '3') (',', '1') (',', ',')
>   (',', ' ') (',', '2') (',', ',') (',', ' ') (',', '3') (' ', '1') ('
>   ', ',') (' ', ' ') (' ', '2') (' ', ',') (' ', ' ') (' ', '3') ('B',
>   '1') ('B', ',') ('B', ' ')

HOW CAN I DO IT PRINT THEM IN THE RIGHT FORM OF "A 1", "A 2", .. "An"
HOW TO REMOVE "," AND " "

Answer (score 1):

A few problems.

You are dealing with *strings* (which are also iterable) on your *input* and you don't need to unpack when calling itertools.product.

The following modifications should do what you want:

```
...
listA.extend(input_listA.split(','))

listB.extend(input_listB.split(','))
...
for i in itertools.product(listA, listB):
    print(i)
```

However, you want to make sure you are feeding `itertools.product` what you intend, and it is not clear on that you are from the post. You need to ensure `listA` and `listB` are lists with the contents on you intend. I believe your intention is:
`['A', 'B', 'C']`
`['1', '2', '3']`
respectively, so for debugging purposes, issue a `print` statement before going into the `for` loop to ensure you have what you want.

My result with sanitized inputs:

```
('A', '1')
('A', '2')
('A', '3')
('B', '1')
('B', '2')
('B', '3')
('C', '1')
('C', '2')
('C', '3')
```

To print into a space separated list:

```
for i in itertools.product(listA, listB):
    print('{} {}'.format(*i))
```

result:

```
A 1
A 2
A 3
B 1
B 2
B 3
C 1
C 2
C 3
```

Comment: THE for i in itertools.product(listA, listB):
    print('{} {}'.format(*i)) IT GIVES A DIFFERENT RESULT THAN YOURS: IT IS A RESULT WITH COMMAS (',') ALONGSIDE THE OTHE A 1
A ,
A 2
A ,
A 3
, 1
, ,
, 2
, ,
, 3
B 1
B ,
B 2
B ,
B 3
, 1
, ,
, 2
, ,
, 3
C 1
C ,
C 2
C ,
C 3

Comment: @A.kaisis you need to make the other modification as well. Extending `listA` and `listB`.

Comment: with them the result is  :                                                                                          a a
a a
a a
a a
, a
, a
, a
, a
b a
b a
b a
b a
, a
, a
, a
, a
c a
c a
c a
c a

Comment: listA=[] #Creating a list
listB=[]#Creating a second list
listC=[]
input_listA=input( "Enter second comma separated list of int: " )
listA.append(input_listA)
listA.extend(input_listA.split(','))

input_listB = input( "Enter first comma separated list of strings: " )
listB.append(input_listB)
listB.extend(input_listB.split(','))

listC.append(listB)
listC.append(listA)


for i in itertools.product(*listA,listB):
    print ('{} {}'.format(*i))

Comment: one more question your code is not functinal when we input words, it taking every character of every string and calculating in the cartesian product it does not calculate it correctly with words

Comment: @A.kaisis that should still work if you are feeding the words separated by commas.